# Used large bottle caps now have uncarbonated beer

Tags: carbonation, caps

Just noticed that i used the large bottle caps on my coffee stout and of course all the beer is not carbonated (tastes fine just not carbonated).

I wanted to make the move to kegging after i went all grain but i rather not loose this batch so i thought i buy a keg and force carbonate this batch. Can this be done even though i added priming sugar? Some of the beers were very lightly carbonated. The beer has been in bottles for about 3 weeks.

I was just going to pour each bottle into the keg, maybe thru a filter? Will i have any issues going this route? Anything else i can do to carbonate the beer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work fine without a filter. Your main problem is going to be oxygenation. When pouring the beer into the keg, take care not to splash, as this will increase the amount of oxygen dissolved in the beer. Dissolved oxygen causes the beer to go stale faster than it otherwise would.

It won't be possible to entirely prevent oxygen from entering the beer, as you're pouring rather than racking. As a consequence, the beer will almost certainly go stale within a number of weeks. You can mitigate this by storing the beer at a cold temperature. Even still, you should drink the beer quickly and not attempt to age it.

Comment: You could add 1/2tsp of ascorbic acid after dumping the beers into the keg - this may help reduce oxidative staling. Also, you can also prime in a keg - add 100g of priming sugar to the batch plus pressurize the keg to 10psi to seal the lid. Leave in a place between 66-75F for a week and the residual yeast will carbonate the beer. They may also scavenge some of the oxygen in the beer. After 5 days carbonating, you can cold crash the beer to serving temps to help preserve it. It will be fully carbonated a week after that.